# Making DynamoDB query with 3 attributes

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a table with orders with the following model:

```
{
  order_id: Hash Key
  timestamp: Attribute
  customer_id: Attribute
  status: Attribute (new, pending, completed, cancelled)
}
```

I need to create a query that gets all orders by customer_id sorted by timestamp that aren't cancelled.

I have created an index with customer_id as the hash key and timestamp as the sort key. However, to retrieve orders with a particular status, I still need to use scan instead of query.
Is it possible to achieve the result only with query?
If not, will the scan actually utilize the fact that there is a hash key in a query, i.e., will it first query by the customer_id and then filter by order status, or will it just comb through all orders anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're specifying a `KeyConditionExpression: "customer_id = :customerId"`, as shown in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SQLtoNoSQL.Indexes.QueryAndScan.html) then yes, only that customer's data will be scanned.

Given your access requirement, you should consider a composite hash or sort key on your index that includes status.

For example, customerId = "1111"

have either a hash key of "1111#COMPLETED" or a sort key of "COMPLETED#2024-03-19-12:05:00.000Z"

Either one would then support a Query operation looking at only the orders with the status you are interested in.

Which way you go depends on rather or not you might want all orders for a customer regardless of status.